# wso2 developing a frontend store front

Tags: php, asp-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

I am interested in develop a frontend similar to the WSO2 API Manager's STORE or PUBLISHER applications. The operations I need to implement would be just something like:

- show all available proxies services (or published services)
- show endpoint of each proxy

What API / libraries should I use in order to do something similar?

Can I build a webapp in php or asp to do that?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the front-end applications of WSO2 API Manager,we have used our inbuilt javascript server-side scripting engine called 'Jaggery'.You can find more info about jaggery from [here.](http://jaggeryjs.org/)

API Manager related back-end functionalities handle through an implemented java API.And its front-end functions handle through javascript/jquery.All the mapping between back-end API Manager related java based functionalities and front-end javascript functionalities handle through this Jaggery scripting engine.
If you view API Publisher/Store source from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/apimgt/api-publisher-web/src/), the app directory structure has implemented as a template engine.A blog post related on How to customize the API Publisher/Store front-end apps can be found from [here](http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.com/2012/07/customizing-wso2-api-storepublisher-app.html).

Other than that to implement API Publisher/Store front-end html views we have used bootstrap framework as described [here.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

Thanks;

Comment: Hi,As a side question,I would like to know the operations you are trying to implement from front-end,are already available with management console service-listing view and what's the requirement you are going to implement them from a new app?

Comment: In the Publisher>Browse>API>"Active Subscriptions" I just wanted to add the number of times the user called that particular API. I already had a look at jaggery, and its structure, unluckily I could not understand how it interact with the database and where is the database that jaggery uses to provide statistics etc....